# Using Fieller's theorem to calculate the confidence interval of a ratio (paired measurements)

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, ratio

If you have two means (with their own confidence intervals) and want to represent them as a ratio, how do calculate the confidence interval for the ratio?

An answer that was given to me, mentions Fieller's theorem, which enables you to compute a confidence interval for a ratio quite easily (see calculator [here](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/ErrorProp1.cfm)).

Unfortunately, I cannot use this tool as my measurements are paired. Is there any way around this?

I might have been clearer in the following image:
[image]

Comment: The fact that your measurements are paired might also play a role on how you compute this ratio. As you work with paired measurement, don't you want to compute the mean ratios (each individual has a ratio, and you mean it) instead of the ratio of the means ?

Comment: The problem is that the were many zeros in the measurements thereby making ratios of paired measurements impossible

Comment: @Marc Then one might question why you're computing ratios in the first place.  If you find yourself in a situation where you literally can't compute something then that makes me question how you are/were planning on interpreting it in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

The problem of calculating confidence/likelihood intervals for the ratio of two means is addressed in Chapter 7 of the book [Statistical Inference in Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950192), and in Chapter 10 of [Empirical Bayes and Likelihood Inference](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-0141-7_10).

Note also that (i) the ratio of the means is different to the [mean of the ratio] `(http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ads/2006/078375/abs/)`, (ii) the distribution of the ratio of two normal variables [is not normal] `(http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00362-012-0429-2#page-1)`.

Comment: These does not really answer the question about using Fiellers' theorem ...